# Prove sequence has optimal length

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, integers

Let there be a sequence of integers such that each term of the sequence is the sum of two previous terms, not necessarily distinct. That is, for sequence $a_i$ with length $\ell$, we require $a_1=1$ and for all $2\le j\le \ell,$ there exist $x,y$ with $1\le x\le y<j$ such that $a_x+a_y=a_j$.

I wish to prove that the shortest possible sequence which reaches $55$ is one with length $9.$ That is, I wish to prove that $a_x=55$ for $1\le x\le 8$ is impossible.

For example, one such sequence is $1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 40, 50, 55$. My intuition is that somehow I should start at $a_9$ and see what other terms are forced when assuming $a_9=55,$ but I'm not sure how to do this without massive amounts of casework.

EDIT: Perhaps I could argue that to get to an odd number, we first need an optimal sequence to a certain even number, then add $1$ to it. I'm still confused as to how to really start this problem, though.

Comment: In this sequence $55 = 5 + 50$. As long as the sequence to get to $5$ is optimal and the sequence to get to $50$ is optimal, the sequence to $55$ is optimal.

Comment: @sku But what if there is a sequence that reaches $55$ without $5$ or without $50$? For example, $1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 49, 55$ works, and doesn't require the optimal sequence to $5$ or to $50$.

Comment: Is that a smaller sequence?

Comment: Is your question how to prove this for an arbitrary generic sequence?

Comment: @sku Yes, how to prove that a length 9 sequence is the shortest sequence possible that ends with $55,$ for an arbitrary generic sequence.

Comment: @sku Maybe there's an argument that the sequences $(1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 49)$ and $(1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 40, 50)$ are equivalent in some way, in some property other than the fact that for both of these sequences, we can get $55$ as a last term?

Comment: For some trivial observations, since $a_2=2$, we can't have a sequence with length $6$ or under that reaches $55$, since the fastest it can grow is $(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32)$. So, we need to prove only that there are no sequences of length $7$ or $8$. One might draw a tree for possible $a_j$'s at each $j$ to find a pattern, etc.

Comment: @JoshuaWoo The tree will be pretty big, and I haven't found a pattern yet. I might try something off of the "fastest it can grow" observation, though.

Comment: I think https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131277/properties-of-shortest-addition-chains-for-small-numbers-e-g-up-to-600?noredirect=1 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706029/an-interesting-property-concerning-a-sequence-of-integers?noredirect=1 regards with these kinds of problems. Actually, I think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain is what your looking for.

Comment: Lots of information on this (general) question at https://oeis.org/A003313 but the definitions there and here are off by one; there, the chain for $n=55$ is said to be of length eight, not nine.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the link, the index started at 0 and not 1, which is why it showed length eight.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete computation.
Say that a finite set $C\subseteq \lbrace 1,2,\ldots$ is an addition chain iff any $x\in C$, $x\neq 1$, can be written as $x=y+z$ with $y,z\in A$ (thus an addition chain always contains $1$). For any finite set $A$, an $A$-chain is an addition chain containing $A$ and contained in $[1..\max(A)]$. Denote by $\mu(A)$ the smallest size of an $A$-chain. Thus, your goal is to compute $\mu(\lbrace 55 \rbrace)$.

The main engine of the computation is the following property : if $m$ is the maximum element of $A$ (assuming $m\gt 1$ to avoid trivialties) and putting $A'=A\setminus \lbrace m \rbrace$, then we have

$$
\mu(A) = 1+\max_{x+y=m,x,y \lt m} \mu(A \cup \lbrace x,y \rbrace) \tag{1}
$$
(the $1+$ comes from adding $m$). In the data below, iterating (1) we successively show inequalities of the form $\mu(A)\geq k$, for some pairs $(A,k)$. The last of those 86 inequalities tells us that $\mu(\lbrace 55 \rbrace) \geq 9$. Now $\lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 22, 33, 55 \rbrace$ is a $55$-chain with $9$ elements, so this result is in fact optimal.

Let me now explain the terse notation in the charts below. Let $n\geq 1$, and let $C$ be an $\lbrace n\rbrace $-chain containing $n$. Then there are $x,y \lt n$ with
$x+y=n$ and $x,y \subseteq C$. Then $|C|\geq 1+\max(\mu(\lbrace x\rbrace),\mu(\lbrace y\rbrace))$. It follows that

$$
\mu(\lbrace n \rbrace ) \geq  1+\min_{x+y=n,x,y \lt n} \max(\mu(\lbrace x\rbrace),\mu(\lbrace y\rbrace)) \tag{2}
$$

For a minority of values of $n$, (2) already gives us all the lower bound we need. Thoses cases are labelled "Simplest case" in the chart below.
For the other cases, the explanations are made by a series of bracketed lists, plus an optional series of braced lists. The braced lists simpy indicate
that a previously computed lower bound is used. The bracketed lists, of the form $[m|L]$, indicate that we consider the case where  the set is of the form $B \cup L$ where $B$ is an $m$-chain. When $L$ is empty, its mention is ommitted and $[m|L]$ reduces to $[m]$.

For example, consider the following random line from the charts below :

$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|l|}
\hline
 A & \mu & \textrm{Explanations}\\
 \hline
\lbrace 3,16 \rbrace & 6 & [13][3|7,9]\ldots\lbrace 3,8 \rbrace\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

This line tells us that the inequality $\mu(\lbrace 3,16 \rbrace) \geq 6$ holds. If $C$ is a $\lbrace 3,16 \rbrace$-chain, then there are $x,y \lt 16$ with $x+y=16$ and $x,y \subseteq C$.

If $13\in\lbrace x,y\rbrace$, then $|C|\geq 1+\mu(\lbrace 13 \rbrace) \geq 6$ by a previous entry in the charts, so we are done in this case. This is indicated by the $[13]$ in the explanations.

If $\lbrace x,y\rbrace = \lbrace 7,9\rbrace=L$, then $C$ contains a subset thatcan be written $B \cup L$ where $B$ is a $\lbrace 3 \rbrace$-chain. It follows that $|C| \geq 1+|L|+\mu(\lbrace 3 \rbrace) \geq 6$ y a previous entry in the charts, so we are done in this case. This is indicated by the $[3|7,9]$ in the explanations.

Finally, if $8\in \lbrace x,y\rbrace$, then $C$ contains $M=\lbrace 3,8 \rbrace$, and hence $ |C| \geq 1+\mu(\lbrace 3,8 \rbrace) \geq 6$ by a previous entry in the charts, so we are done in this case. This is indicated by the $\lbrace 3,8 \rbrace$ in the explanations.

$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|l|}
\hline
 A & \mu & \textrm{Explanations}\\
\hline
2 & 2 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
3 & 3 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
4 & 3 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
5 & 4 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
6 & 4 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 7 \rbrace & 5 & [3|4][5][6]\\
\hline
\lbrace 3,8 \rbrace & 5 & [3|4][3|5][2|3,6][3|7]\\
\hline
8 & 4 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
9 & 5 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
10 & 5 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 11 \rbrace & 6 & [5|6][7][9][10]\lbrace 3,8 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 5,12 \rbrace & 6 & [5|6][5|7][4|5,8][3|5,9][5|10][5|11]\\
\hline
12 & 5 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 13 \rbrace & 6 & [6|7][5|8][9][10][11][12]\\
\hline
\lbrace 14 \rbrace & 6 & [7][6|8][5|9][10][11][12][13]\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|l|}
\hline
 A & \mu & \textrm{Explanations}\\
\hline
15 & 6 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 3,16 \rbrace & 6 & [13][3|7,9][3|6,10][3|5,11][3|4,12][14][15]\lbrace 3,8 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 5,16 \rbrace & 6 & [5|8][5|11][5|7,9][5|6,10][4|5,12][3|5,13][5|14][5|15]\\
\hline
\lbrace 6,16 \rbrace & 6 & [6|8][6|10][6|7,9][5|6,11][4|6,12][3|6,13][6|14][6|15]\\
\hline
\lbrace 7,16 \rbrace & 7 & [7|8][7|9][6|7,10][5|7,11][7|12][7|13][7|14][7|15]\\
\hline
16 & 5 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 12,17 \rbrace & 7 & [8|9,12][7|10,12][6|11,12][12|13][12|14][12|15][12|16]\lbrace 5,12 \rbrace\\
\hline
17 & 6 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
18 & 6 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 19 \rbrace & 7 & [9|10][11][7|12][13][14][15][17][18]\lbrace 3,16 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 7,20 \rbrace & 7 & [7|10][7|13][7|9,11][7|8,12][6|7,14][5|7,15][7|16][7|17][7|18][7|19]\\
\hline
\lbrace 9,20 \rbrace & 7 & [9|10][9|11][8|9,12][7|9,13][6|9,14][5|9,15][9|16][9|17][9|18][9|19]\\
\hline
20 & 6 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 21 \rbrace & 7 & [10|11][9|12][13][7|14][15][17][18][19][20]\lbrace 5,16 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 22 \rbrace & 7 & [11][10|12][9|13][14][7|15][17][18][19][20][21]\lbrace 6,16 \rbrace\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|l|}
\hline
 A & \mu & \textrm{Explanations}\\
\hline
\lbrace 23 \rbrace & 7 & [11|12][10|13][9|14][15][7|16][17][18][19][20][21][22]\\
\hline
\lbrace 5,24 \rbrace & 7 & [19][5|11,13][5|10,14][5|9,15][5|8,16][5|7,17][5|6,18][20][21][22][23]\lbrace 5,12 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 7,24 \rbrace & 7 & [7|12][7|17][7|11,13][7|10,14][7|9,15][7|8,16][6|7,18][5|7,19][7|20][7|21][7|22][7|23]\\
\hline
24 & 6 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 25 \rbrace & 7 & [12|13][11|14][10|15][9|16][17][7|18][19][20][21][22][23][24]\\
\hline
\lbrace 26 \rbrace & 7 & [13][12|14][11|15][10|16][9|17][18][7|19][20][21][22][23][24][25]\\
\hline
\lbrace 20,27 \rbrace & 8 & [13|14,20][12|15,20][11|16,20][10|17,20][9|18,20][19|20][20|21][20|22][20|23][20|24][20|25][20|26]\lbrace 7,20 \rbrace\\
\hline
27 & 7 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 28 \rbrace & 7 & [14][13|15][12|16][11|17][10|18][9|19][20][7|21][22][23][24][25][26][27]\\
\hline
\lbrace 29 \rbrace & 8 & [14|15][13|16][11|18][19][21][22][23][25][26][27][28]\lbrace 12,17 \rbrace\lbrace 9,20 \rbrace\lbrace 5,24 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 17,30 \rbrace & 8 & [13|17][15|17][14|16,17][12|17,18][11|17,19][10|17,20][9|17,21][17|22][7|17,23][17|24][17|25][17|26][17|27][17|28][17|29]\\
\hline
30 & 7 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 31 \rbrace & 8 & [15|16][14|17][13|18][19][11|20][21][22][23][25][26][27][28][29][30]\lbrace 7,24 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 5,16,32 \rbrace & 7 & [5|16,27][5|15,16,17][5|14,16,18][5|13,16,19][5|12,16,20][5|11,16,21][5|10,16,22][5|9,16,23][5|8,16,24][5|7,16,25][5|6,16,26][4|5,16,28][3|5,16,29][5|16,30][5|16,31]\lbrace 5,16 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 3,32 \rbrace & 7 & [29][15|17][14|18][13|19][12|20][11|21][10|22][9|23][24][7|25][26][27][28][30][31]\lbrace 3,16 \rbrace\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|l|}
\hline
 A & \mu & \textrm{Explanations}\\
\hline
\lbrace 5,32 \rbrace & 7 & [27][5|15,17][5|14,18][5|13,19][5|12,20][5|11,21][5|10,22][5|9,23][5|8,24][5|7,25][5|6,26][28][29][30][31]\lbrace 5,16 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 6,32 \rbrace & 7 & [26][6|15,17][6|14,18][6|13,19][6|12,20][6|11,21][6|10,22][6|9,23][6|8,24][6|7,25][5|6,27][28][29][30][31]\lbrace 6,16 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 7,32 \rbrace & 8 & [25][7|15,17][7|14,18][7|13,19][7|12,20][7|11,21][7|10,22][7|9,23][7|8,24][26][27][28][29][30][31]\lbrace 7,16 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 9,32 \rbrace & 7 & [9|16][9|23][9|15,17][9|14,18][9|13,19][9|12,20][9|11,21][9|10,22][8|9,24][7|9,25][6|9,26][5|9,27][9|28][9|29][9|30][9|31]\\
\hline
\lbrace 10,32 \rbrace & 7 & [10|16][10|22][10|15,17][10|14,18][10|13,19][10|12,20][10|11,21][9|10,23][8|10,24][7|10,25][6|10,26][5|10,27][10|28][10|29][10|30][10|31]\\
\hline
\lbrace 12,32 \rbrace & 7 & [12|16][12|20][12|15,17][12|14,18][12|13,19][11|12,21][10|12,22][9|12,23][8|12,24][7|12,25][6|12,26][5|12,27][12|28][12|29][12|30][12|31]\\
\hline
\lbrace 15,32 \rbrace & 8 & [15|16][15|17][14|15,18][13|15,19][12|15,20][11|15,21][10|15,22][9|15,23][15|24][7|15,25][15|26][15|27][15|28][15|29][15|30][15|31]\\
\hline
32 & 6 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 14,33 \rbrace & 8 & [14|19][14|16,17][14|15,18][13|14,20][12|14,21][11|14,22][10|14,23][9|14,24][14|25][7|14,26][14|27][14|28][14|29][14|30][14|31][14|32]\\
\hline
\lbrace 20,33 \rbrace & 8 & [13|20][16|17,20][15|18,20][14|19,20][12|20,21][11|20,22][10|20,23][9|20,24][20|25][7|20,26][20|27][20|28][20|29][20|30][20|31][20|32]\\
\hline
33 & 7 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 13,34 \rbrace & 8 & [13|17][13|21][13|16,18][13|15,19][13|14,20][12|13,22][11|13,23][10|13,24][9|13,25][13|26][7|13,27][13|28][13|29][13|30][13|31][13|32][13|33]\\
\hline
34 & 7 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 35 \rbrace & 8 & [17|18][19][15|20][14|21][13|22][23][11|24][25][26][27][28][29][30][31][33][34]\lbrace 3,32 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 11,36 \rbrace & 8 & [11|18][11|25][11|17,19][11|16,20][11|15,21][11|14,22][11|13,23][11|12,24][10|11,26][9|11,27][11|28][7|11,29][11|30][11|31][11|32][11|33][11|34][11|35]\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|l|}
\hline
 A & \mu & \textrm{Explanations}\\
\hline
\lbrace 17,36 \rbrace & 8 & [17|18][17|19][16|17,20][15|17,21][14|17,22][13|17,23][12|17,24][11|17,25][10|17,26][9|17,27][17|28][7|17,29][17|30][17|31][17|32][17|33][17|34][17|35]\\
\hline
36 & 7 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 37 \rbrace & 8 & [18|19][17|20][21][15|22][14|23][13|24][25][11|26][27][28][29][30][31][33][34][35][36]\lbrace 5,32 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 38 \rbrace & 8 & [19][18|20][17|21][22][15|23][14|24][13|25][26][11|27][28][29][30][31][33][34][35][36][37]\lbrace 6,32 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 39 \rbrace & 8 & [19|20][18|21][17|22][23][15|24][14|25][13|26][27][11|28][29][30][31][33][34][35][36][37][38]\lbrace 7,32 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 7,40 \rbrace & 8 & [33][7|19,21][7|18,22][7|17,23][7|16,24][7|15,25][7|14,26][7|13,27][7|12,28][7|11,29][7|10,30][7|9,31][7|8,32][34][35][36][37][38][39]\lbrace 7,20 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 13,40 \rbrace & 8 & [13|20][13|27][13|19,21][13|18,22][13|17,23][13|16,24][13|15,25][13|14,26][12|13,28][11|13,29][10|13,30][9|13,31][13|32][7|13,33][13|34][13|35][13|36][13|37][13|38][13|39]\\
\hline
\lbrace 15,40 \rbrace & 8 & [15|20][15|25][15|19,21][15|18,22][15|17,23][15|16,24][14|15,26][13|15,27][12|15,28][11|15,29][10|15,30][9|15,31][15|32][7|15,33][15|34][15|35][15|36][15|37][15|38][15|39]\\
\hline
40 & 7 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 41 \rbrace & 8 & [20|21][19|22][18|23][17|24][25][15|26][14|27][13|28][29][11|30][31][33][34][35][36][37][38][39][40]\lbrace 9,32 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 42 \rbrace & 8 & [21][20|22][19|23][18|24][17|25][26][15|27][14|28][13|29][30][11|31][33][34][35][36][37][38][39][40][41]\lbrace 10,32 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 43 \rbrace & 8 & [21|22][20|23][19|24][18|25][17|26][27][15|28][14|29][13|30][31][11|32][33][34][35][36][37][38][39][40][41][42]\\
\hline
\lbrace 44 \rbrace & 8 & [22][21|23][20|24][19|25][18|26][17|27][28][15|29][14|30][13|31][11|33][34][35][36][37][38][39][40][41][42][43]\lbrace 12,32 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 45 \rbrace & 8 & [22|23][21|24][20|25][19|26][18|27][17|28][29][15|30][14|31][13|32][33][11|34][35][36][37][38][39][40][41][42][43][44]\\
\hline
\lbrace 46 \rbrace & 8 & [23][22|24][21|25][20|26][19|27][18|28][17|29][30][15|31][14|32][13|33][34][11|35][36][37][38][39][40][41][42][43][44][45]\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|l|}
\hline
 A & \mu & \textrm{Explanations}\\
\hline
\lbrace 47 \rbrace & 9 & [23|24][22|25][21|26][19|28][29][31][35][37][38][39][41][42][43][44][45][46]\lbrace 20,27 \rbrace\lbrace 17,30 \rbrace\lbrace 15,32 \rbrace\lbrace 14,33 \rbrace\lbrace 13,34 \rbrace\lbrace 11,36 \rbrace\lbrace 7,40 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 5,48 \rbrace & 8 & [43][23|25][22|26][21|27][20|28][19|29][18|30][17|31][15|33][14|34][13|35][36][11|37][38][39][40][41][42][44][45][46][47]\lbrace 5,24 \rbrace\lbrace 5,16,32 \rbrace\\
\hline
\lbrace 7,48 \rbrace & 8 & [41][7|23,25][7|22,26][7|21,27][7|20,28][7|19,29][7|18,30][7|17,31][7|16,32][7|15,33][7|14,34][7|13,35][7|12,36][7|11,37][7|10,38][7|9,39][7|8,40][42][43][44][45][46][47]\lbrace 7,24 \rbrace\\
\hline
48 & 7 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 49 \rbrace & 8 & [24|25][23|26][22|27][21|28][20|29][19|30][18|31][17|32][33][15|34][14|35][13|36][37][11|38][39][40][41][42][43][44][45][46][47][48]\\
\hline
\lbrace 50 \rbrace & 8 & [25][24|26][23|27][22|28][21|29][20|30][19|31][18|32][17|33][34][15|35][14|36][13|37][38][11|39][40][41][42][43][44][45][46][47][48][49]\\
\hline
51 & 8 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 52 \rbrace & 8 & [26][25|27][24|28][23|29][22|30][21|31][20|32][19|33][18|34][17|35][36][15|37][14|38][13|39][40][11|41][42][43][44][45][46][47][48][49][50][51]\\
\hline
\lbrace 53 \rbrace & 9 & [26|27][25|28][29][23|30][22|31][21|32][19|34][35][37][38][39][41][42][43][44][45][46][47][49][50][51][52]\lbrace 20,33 \rbrace\lbrace 17,36 \rbrace\lbrace 13,40 \rbrace\lbrace 5,48 \rbrace\\
\hline
54 & 8 & \textrm{Simplest case}\\
\hline
\lbrace 55 \rbrace & 9 & [27|28][26|29][25|30][31][23|32][22|33][21|34][35][19|36][37][38][39][41][42][43][44][45][46][47][49][50][51][52][53][54]\lbrace 15,40 \rbrace\lbrace 7,48 \rbrace\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Any idea how long it takes this algorithm to run, as a function of $n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The complexity seems to be linear : Here, to compute $\mu(\lbrace 55 \rbrace)$ we need to compute $\mu(A)$ for $86$ other sets $A$, my guess would be that to get $\mu(\lbrace n \rbrace)$ you need to compute $\mu(A)$ for around $2n$ other sets $A$. Notice also how $\mu(A)$ depends mostly on the largest elements in $A$ : of all the additional $\mu(A)$'s computed here, only one of them has three elements, namely $\lbrace 5,16,32 \rbrace$. This makes the recursion somewhat shallow and easy to manage.